# Dropbox Core API - 1021 error before upload - only in iOS 5 and below

Tags: ios, file-upload, dropbox

I integrated dropbox core API with two of my iOS apps. Successfully. A few weeks ago, it was working fine. But now when I run those apps on devices with iOS 5.0 or iOS 4.2, and try to call the uploadFile: API, I get this error:

`error making request to /1/files_put/sandbox/abc.xyz - (-1021) Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1021 "The operation couldnÕt be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1021.)" UserInfo=0x28af00 {destinationPath=/abc.xyz, sourcePath=/var/mobile/Applications/FB0373C9-...C4F0874D40/Documents/abc.xyz}`

where abc.xyz is the file name I am trying to upload.

-1021 error code usually comes in case of authentication failure while uploading. That too AFTER the file has been uploaded.
But this time it appears even before the upload starts.

I tried loadMetadata: API, it works fine, and returns the metadata.

On 2 devices with the latest iOS installed, dropbox upload works fine.
I tried updating to latest SDK, but even then it doesn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16117275/1059705 this might help you

Comment: @Bala The link actually solves the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this build it works fine with me in iOS 5,6 from [Dropbox Forum](https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=102898)

Also you can download the build from [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vy2dq3jzfv90w5g/dropbox-ios-sdk-1.3.5-b3.tar.gz)

Comment: yeah, I also asked a question on the forum, and got a similar reply with the corrected build.